# Is it possible to have choice column in SharePoint list with hyperlink values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, hyperlink, office-365-developer

I have one list, in that one choice column for that I have multiple values.

I want to make all this multiple values as clickable. (means:each values correspond to some URL)

Answer (score 0):

No OOB way to achieve it.

A simple workaround, create a calculated column, show different hyperlinks based on different choice values.

How to show hyperlink via Calculated column: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/calculated-column-html-fix-sharepoint-online-april-dunnam